# How to delete object from NSSet in relation one to Many in Core Data using NSFechedResultController?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

My Core Data graph has to Entity namely, APBook Entity has a 1 to many relation to APCLippingExtract. A book can have many clippings.
 RootTableViewController which displays Author name in section and their books in rows. In the DetailTableViewController, data is fetched from APClippingExtract Entity as below -

```
@implementation DetailTableViewController

#pragma mark - fetchedResultController
- (NSFetchedResultsController*) fetchedResultController {

if (_fetchedResultController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultController;
}

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"APClippingExtract"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"extract" ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"extractFromBook == %@", self.currentBook]];

request.fetchBatchSize = 20;
_fetchedResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.mainContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

//dlegating for NSfetchedResultController
_fetchedResultController.delegate =self;

return _fetchedResultController;
}
```

When user deletes the row with clipping, below method is used to delete it from Entity.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.mainContext;
    APClippingExtract *clippingToDelete = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [context deleteObject:clippingToDelete];

    [eeCoreStack saveMainContext];

}
}
```

EECoreStack is custom class for Core Stack setUp// saving method is below

```
- (void)saveMainContext {
[self.mainContext performBlock:^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.mainContext save:&error];
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"ERROR SAVING MAIN MOC %@: %@:", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
    }else {
        [self saveMasterContext];
    }
}];
}

- (void)saveMasterContext {

    [self.masterContext performBlock:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        [self.masterContext save:&error];
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"ERROR SAVING MASTER CONTEXT %@; : %@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

The Problem is when deleting the row, when going back to RootTableViewController , numberOfClipping count do not change.

**There is a method in APBook category**

```
- (void)removeSmallClippings:(NSSet<APClippingExtract *> *)values;
```

For above to work, need to fetch APBook attribute. Since I am currently fetching APClippingExtract in DetialTableViewController.

Kindly correct, if it is wrong.

**EDIT 1:**

**RootTableViewController**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ListSegue"]){

    ListTableViewController *destination = (ListTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    APBook *selectedBook = (APBook*)[self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    destination.currentBook = selectedBook;
    destination.mainContext = self.mainContext;
    destination.workerContext = self.workerContext;


    destination.deleteNow = ^(APClippingExtract *deleteClipping){
        [self.mainContext deleteObject:deleteClipping];
        deleteClipping.extractFromBook.numberOfClippings = deleteClipping.extractFromBook.numberOfClippings;
        [eeCoreStack saveMainContext];

    };
}
}
```

**In DetailTableViewController**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    APClippingExtract *clippingToDelete = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.deleteNow(clippingToDelete);


}
```

}

Comment: I am using this method to delete object from NSSet, still when I go back to RootTableViewController, Table not updates.                                                         `APClippingExtract *clippingToDelete = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   NSMutableSet *mutableSet = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:self.currentBook.smallClippings];
        [mutableSet removeObject:clippingToDelete];
        self.currentBook.smallClippings = mutableSet;
        NSLog(@"Sel book clippingis %i", (int)[self.currentBook.smallClippings count]);
       
  [eeCoreStack saveMainContext];
`

Comment: After reloading table View when seguing back, count of clippings is showing correctly. But don't we use NSFetchedResultController so that we do not have to do [tableView reloadData] explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying an object (inc. deletion) does not trigger any updates in its related objects.  This means that FRCs that are watching the related object won't fire.  What you have to do is modify the related object yourself.  I don't know what properties you have, precisely, but here's an example.

```
clipping.book.title = clipping.book.title; // This will trigger FRCs watching book entities.

[context deleteObject:clipping];
```

Comment: Do you have specific problem you are trying to ask about?  Is there something unclear about my answer?

Comment: Please look at this screenShot of [Model graph](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8athk42wcrme1ra/AACc0Kg8UjgMy7dhvTXIB6WRa?dl=0). I have edited my post. reloading tableview does the work, but it is not efficient. I have read other post where it says to create another attribute of same kind on both Entity.

Comment: I am trying to Update FRC by  deleteClipping.extractFromBook.numberOfClippings =  deleteClipping.extractFromBook.numberOfClippings. It is not working.

Comment: I am sending APClipping object back toRootViewController on seguing back where I save the context and even after updating FRC as you mentioned, there is no changes in TableView. It only works when I close the app and restart.

Comment: Are you sure the FRC for `APBook` is triggered, and do you handle `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete` events?

Comment: Yes , I am. When I delete a book attribute eg, title from RootTableViewCotroller tableView, it gets deleted from there and I get the delete row animation as well. It is only when I delete its relationship in ListTableViewController(in there also it get removed from TableView) and when delete it from RootView after seguing back as shown in code, it does not work, not until I reload tableview or restart app.

Comment: I may have seen a similar bug.  Your only recourse may be to `reloadData` in `viewWillAppear:`.